# Forms: Sharepoint or Infopath & SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services, form

This is really more of a strategic question.

My company is looking at electronic forms in SP2010 (running a mix of InfoPath 2007 & 2010).
We currently run Office 2003 & MOSS2007 and run a number of smaller Infopath forms with OOB workflow.

My question is, as we delve further into this solution in 2010, is it best to develop these as InfoPath forms with custom workflows, lookups etc, or build the entire forms/process as a SharePoint WebApp?

Some examples for work will include asset acquisition forms, to employee hire etc.

I'd rather ask the experts now before I get 6 months down the track and realize I should have taken it in a different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoPath 2010 has come with lot more of options and complexities that InfoPath 2007 had difficulties with. I have developed numerous forms in both the versions and I believe InfoPath 2010 is a good bet for many of the complexities that you may come across rather than spending time on third party components.

SharePoint designer 2010 workflows have also improved, but to a limited extent. You can always create Visual Studio WorkFlows for any complex situations that you encounter with workflows.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. I'll try and make do with the IP2007 untill we can migrate all machines to make the most of it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are going to do with your forms and how complex they are.
my personal opinion is that InfoPath is a hassle.

to make your forms over SharePoint you will need to use 3rd party components. by this way you won't have to purchase the expensive enterprise version of SharePoint and use just the standard or even the SharePoint foundation.

have a look on those:
http://www.bpc-components.com/
http://www.infowisesolutions.com/bundle.aspx?id=UltimateForms

you also have demo applications here: 
http://www.infowisesolutions.com/applications.aspx

Comment: Those are some great little tools. But I'm always a little wary about 3rd party tools. The issue is, whilst they are extremely flexible, sometimes you hit a point when you need to stretch the function in a slightly different direction, and your not always able to. But of course that is purely speculation in regards to these tools. I can see a lot of use in them for a company that has their requirements properly specced out. Unfortunately where I work, people will change their requirements every 5 minutes...